# Adjusted R Squared With More Features Than Samples

Tags: regression, goodness-of-fit

**Background:** I am working on a project involving fitting a linear regression from EEG data to image features. The nature of the experiments I run to gather data mean I have to work with very few samples (360) and the raw EEG has 7680 features. I have been using the SKLearn Ridge, and I tried to measure the level of fit using its score function adjusted as detailed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Adjusted_R2).

**Problem:** This adjustment was actually increasing the fit rather than decreasing it and looking at the formula I gather this will be the case any time there are more features than samples (where p > n).

**Question:** Is there some way to measure goodness of fit for linear regression when there are more features than samples (or observations)?

Comment: Could you explain what your term "adjustment" is referring to?  The use of adjusted $R^2$ is mysterious because the formula is only for cases where there are more observations than features; it makes no sense to apply it otherwise.

Comment: This isn't really clear (for starters, I think your title should be '... more features than samples' to match your Q), & I don't think it's answerable at present.

Comment: You're right thank you for pointing that out, I have corrected the terms in my question. I am looking for some way to measure goodness of fit when there are more features than samples.

Comment: To me, the OPs question has less to do with the metric "adjusted R-squared" than with an appropriate analytic methodology for the special case where there are more features than sample. The thing to note is that classic tests and multivariate tools aren't appropriate for this special case since the degrees of freedom are exhausted. Chemometrics is an industry where this special case of features>>sample is common and is also where workarounds to it such as partial least squares (PLS) were developed. There are others, but PLS is a good place to start in terms of an appropriate analytic framework